# Sencha touch 2 how to reference to a list item with in view?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am new to Sencha Touch. I have a list inside a view. I would like to refer to the list with in initial function of the view. And with in the function, I am going to set store to the list.

My View:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.view.tablet.MainMenu',{
extend:'Ext.Container',
xtype:'mainMenu',
    id:'mainMenu',

    requires:['Ext.TitleBar','Ext.dataview.List'],
config:{
            loggedInUser:'',
    fullscreen:true,
            tabBarPosition: 'top',
    items:[{
        xtype:'titlebar',
        title:'NetCenter APP',
        items:[{
               xtype:'list',
               id:'menuList',
               itemCls:'listItem'
            }
        ]

    }]


},

    initialize: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
               xtype: 'loadmask',
               message: 'Loading ...'
           });
           var moduleStore=Ext.create('NCAPP.store.Module');
           moduleStore.load({
               callback:function(records,operation,success){
                    Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                    // I would like to refer to the list here and set store to it
                    var menu=this.menulist;
                    menu.setStore(moduleStore);
                    console.log(records);
               },
               scope:this
           });
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me please? Thanks

My Model:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.model.Module', {
extend:'Ext.data.Model',

config:{
    fields:[
        { name:'id', type: 'int'},
        { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'description', type:'string'}
        ]
}
```

});

And my store:

```
Ext.define('NCAPP.store.Module',{
extend:'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    model:'NCAPP.model.Module',

    autoLoad:false,
    proxy: {
        type:'rest',
        url:NCAPP.app.baseApiUrl+'/user/module/1/',
        noCache: false,

        //limitParam: false,
        //enablePagingParams: false,
       // startParam: false,

        reader: {
            type:'json',
            rootProperty:'modules'
        }


    }
```

}

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've already set `id` for your list, then you just need to use [Ext.getCmp()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp) to retrieve your list:

```
var menu = Ext.getCmp("menuList");
menu.setStore(moduleStore);
```

To populate the list afterwards, try [refresh](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.DataView-method-refresh):

```
menu.refresh();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now how can I populate the list with store? (I have edited the question with model and store code)

Comment: You can give your store a `storeId` then get store by using `var moduleStore = Ext.getStore(storeId)` and set store like above